# I can't change my OpenId to a different ID WITH THE SAME PROVIDER

Tags: support, openid

Sorry for the caps in the title. I did that because there are a ton of requests that look similar from before the ability to change providers was added.

So I want to use a different Google Account than the one I was using when I created this account here. However, when I follow the instructions to change it and click on the Google Accounts icon, it doesn't work because I'm already logged in via Google. It just goes in circles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must log all the way out of Google for this to work -- or use a different web browser (which has no cookies set).

Comment: I really should have thought of that myself ... Thanks!